# Store file in a shared place in Android

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-file

In my project, I have a need to store a file to a place which can be accessed by **all user accounts** on the same Android device (phone & tablet). Besides, store it in SD card, is there any other place available in Android? What are the other options I can have?

Comment: Why -1 ? Just because I don't have code ? It is a general question doesn't need code . I need suggestions, what is wrong with that?

Comment: Do you want to access the file only from with in the App you are making. Or the file can be accessed by any outside app?

Comment: And what kind of file is it?

Comment: I need a place can be accessed cross user accounts on the same device (it implies outside app). The type of file is not a concern of my question. My concern is the place where to put the file, what are the options I can have. If you insist me to give a type of file, well, txt file.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Documentation on publicly accessible directory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String))

Just use:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory (String type);
```

This will give a directory that is accessible by any app or user.

Comment: Like I said, I need a place other than SD card, Android document says `getExternalStorageDirectory()` traditionally is SD card, though it could be some other internal storage. But I need a place which is not SD card.

Comment: ExternalStorage does not necessarily mean SD card, but I get your point

Answer (score 0):

Look into content provider. I think this might be an option for you. It is a a complicated concept to understand at first. But I am sure this will resolve the issue if you need to create a document within your app. Save it somewhere , where other apps can access it and alter it.

[Google Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html)

Comment: Thanks, I will check it, but are you sure it can be accessed by different user accounts on the same device as well?

Comment: Yes, You will see that if you look into it. You will need to be careful how you create you data model. What I mean is to make the data accessible by the apps you want and allowing any user to access it without any password or constriction.